# Use jQuery to remove element and stop if element contains specific filename

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a fairly dumb plugin that doesn't yet know how to remove a Video tag entirely if the source filename ends with the wrong file extension.

Pseudo code works like this:

```
Div populates with a Video element
If Video element SRC isn't a .M4V file name extension, remove the parent div including the Video element
If Video element SRC is a .M4V file extension, behaves as normal.
```

The code I have now isn't working, but I'm not sure where to look for a good solution. Is it just my syntax?

```
        $('.aboveTheFold video').(function(){
             if( $('video #postvideo').attr('src').match(/\.(m4v)/) ) {
                $("#postvideo").detach().appendTo("#fold-above");
             } else if {
                $('#postvideo').attr('src').match(/\.(jpg)/) )
                {
                    $('.aboveTheFold video').remove();
                };
             }
        });
```

A simplified way of doing it is this:

```
    $("#postvideo").attr('src').match(/\.(jpg)/) ).remove();
```

But the console is now telling me there is a missing bracket in the jquery.min, which I'm sure is not the case...

Comment: Change your else if to an else

Comment: and move the `if` to the next line

Comment: Also why are you trying to match the .jpg extension when your pseudo code doesn't mention it?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm trying to match that because I haven't seen any ways to implement a wild card solution.

Comment: I think you meant `} else if (` instead of `} else if {` in your code. If you change the `{` to `(`, that part will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is definitely wrong; the `.(function...` syntax isn't valid JavaScript. You need a function name between the `.` and the `(`, and you're probably looking for the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

If I understand what you're trying to do, it sounds like  you can just do this:

```
$('.aboveTheFold video #postvideo')   
      .not('[src$=".m4v"]')          //elements whose src doesn't end with `.m4v`
      .each(function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
      });
```

If you want to match against a regex, you can also pass a callback to the `not` function:

```
.not(function() {
   return !/\.m4v/.test($(this).attr('src'));
})
```

BUT...note that `#postvideo` is an ID, and your code looks like you have more than one element with that ID. You shouldn't have duplicate IDs on a page; it could lead to unpredictable or buggy behavior. I suggest you change that to a class.

Comment: In the few minutes it took you to suss this out, it's taken me a week of learning and remembering jQuery. I'd high five you case of beer, but instead you get the answer check mark.

Comment: @canacast - Glad I could help! Wish I could take you up on that beer offer, though.